# Python: Using 'getcontext().prec' from the decimal module for controling the number of digits prinited of an infinite number

Tags: python, algorithm, factorial, pi, eulers-number

I am working on a project that generates an infinite number like PI (3.141...etc) or Euler's number(2.718...etc). It asks the user how many digits they would like to generate then runs an algorithm that will accurately generate that many digits.

Coding the algorithms went well and they work as desired. Now I am attempting to implement a way to control the number of digits that are printed. I am doing this using the **getcontext()** function from the **decimal** module. Here is the Euler's number function for example.

**2.7182818284590452353602874713527** <--- (Euler's number for reference)

```
from math import factorial
from decimal import getcontext, Decimal
```

```
e = 0
```

```
def euler_gen:
  for n in range(0,100):
    n = factorial(n)
    e += 1/n

    getcontext().prec = 5
    print(Decimal(e))
```

The intended output is **2.7182**. Instead **52** digits are printed. Am I misusing the function or is there a differant solution you would recommend for solving this issue?

Comment: This isn't legal Python code.

Comment: @scottHunter Would you be able to explain why this is illegal python code?

Comment: `def euler_gen:`: SyntaxError.  You might want to check your Python interpreter.